# How to use Left Join to get the row holding the maximum of a certain column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This is an example from [mysql5.6Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-maximum-row.html).

Suppose there's a table in MySQL database called 'shop'. Each row in the table represents a different item in the shop, which has the field 'article', 'dealer' and 'price'.

In order to find the most expensive item, I can simply use MySQL code:

```
SELECT article, dealer, price
FROM shop
ORDER BY price DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

However, what if I want to use the LEFT JOIN to implement the same effect?
The documentation suggests that I can write something like

```
SELECT s1.article, s1.dealer, s1.price
FROM shop s1
LEFT JOIN  shop s2 ON s1.price < s2.price
WHERE s2.article IS NULL;
```

I don't quite understand the usage of LEFT JOIN here, especially the condition after WHERE keyword. Can anyone help me on this? I'd appreciate your help!

Comment: This is a so-called anti join pattern. You can re-write such queries with `NOT EXISTS` which are more readable (in your case: select records for which *not exists* a record with a higher price). Anti joins are normally used when you have performance issues with a not exists query (i.e. when the DBMS optimizer does a bad job on that query).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key to this rather clever solution is using a left join along with a null "where" condition.

A left join always returns rows from the main table, whether there are matching rows in the joined table or not - quite different to an INNER join (the default if you just use "join"), which only returns rows when there is a match between both tables.

So what happens here is that we join the tables not on raw fields, but on a derived value (s1.price < s2.price), which means a lower price in the main table and a higher price in the joined table.

If, therefore, there is no higher price, we know we have selected the highest price. And under this condition, the left joined table will not return a row, hence any column that we check will be null. It's actually not important which field we check in the where clause - any field from s2 will do.

For more, take a read of the mysql docs on join types: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: Thank you Simon! Your explanation is really clear and easy to understand :)

Comment: Pleasure, can you "accept" the answer in that case? Gives me some more brownie points!

Answer (score 0):

`s1.price < s2.price` finds items in the right table that are more expensive than the left. If the item on the left has nothing of higher price, the `article` column on the right will be `null`